# ¿Cuál sería mi "puntuación de candidato" en la elección de moderadores?

Tags: soporte, medallas, elecciones

Ahora que estamos en la fase de postulación de las [primeras elecciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1) te habrás fijado en que la tabla con datos contiene la leyenda *puntuación del candidato*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Te ha picado la curiosidad por saber cuáles serían tus números? ¿Qué medallas te faltan?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### ¿Cuál sería mi puntuación de candidato?

Estos datos se pueden conseguir mediante [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Obtén tu identificador de usuario: fíjate en la dirección de [tu perfil](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current), que es de la forma `https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/XXX/tu_nombre`. Pues ese `XXX` es tu identificador, que debes escribir como parámetro de las consultas siguientes.

- Puntuación del candidato → [Candidate score](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/298418/candidate-score)
- Medallas que te faltan para tener el "pleno":

  - [Badges missing from election candidate score](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/390710/badges-missing-from-election-candidate-score)
  - [Medallas faltantes en puntuacion de candidato](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/705378/medallas-faltantes-en-puntuacion-de-candidato)

Además, puedes ver la lista de usuarios ordenados según su puntuación de candidato en: [Moderator Election Score for all eligible candidates with score > 1](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/581305/moderator-election-score-for-all-eligible-candidates-with-score-1).

---

#### ¿Cómo se calcula la puntuación de candidato?

Adaptado de [What are the details on the “candidate score” which shows during an election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252643/209901), tenemos:

La puntuación de candidato tiene un valor entero entre 0 y 40 y se calcula así:

- 1 punto por cada 1000 puntos de reputación hasta llegar a los 20 puntos para quien tenga 20 000 o más.
- 1 punto por cada una de las medallas de moderación:  [Obligación Civil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty), [Limpieza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup), [Ayudante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/70/deputy), [Electorado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate), [Mariscal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal), [Revisor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/78/reviewer), [Espíritu deportivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship) y [Encargado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/steward), hasta llegar a un máximo de 8 puntos.
- 1 punto por cada una de las medallas de edición:  [Editor de textos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor), [Explicador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/90/explainer), [Organizador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer), [Refinador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/91/refiner), [Cervantes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) y [Editor de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/58/tag-editor), hasta llegar a un máximo de 6 puntos.
- 1 punto por cada una de las medallas de participación: [Votante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/81/constituent), [Convención](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/68/convention), [Entusiasta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/54/enthusiast), [Inversor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/45/investor), [Quórum](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/67/quorum) y [Añejo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling), hasta llegar a un máximo de 6 puntos.

En aquellas medallas que pueden ser obtenidas más de una vez solamente se puede conseguir 1 punto.

La puntuación se calcula basándose en el estado actual del candidato, por lo que las puntuaciones en elecciones anteriores no reflejarán el estado del candidato en el momento en que aquella elección tenía lugar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación @fedorqui, la verdad es que tenia curiosidad por ver cómo sería mi puntuación la verdad,aún tengo que mejorar sólo tengo 12/40

Comment: ¿Falta alguna medalla en esas consultas? La nota más alta es 40, yo tengo 37 (llegando al límite de 20 por reputación) y pone que me faltan 2 medallas que haría 39.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro medallas son 20: 8 de moderación, 6 de edición y 6 de participación. Tú tienes 6-6-5, luego te faltan: [Mariscal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal?userid=250), [Encargado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/steward?userid=250) y.... [Votante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/81/constituent?userid=250) esta última es obvio que no puedes conseguirla hasta que se llegue a la fase final de las elecciones. [Fuente](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289504/1983854).

Comment: Ah... tiene truco :P

Comment: @fedorqui He modificado la consulta que agregaste, y he hecho una version en Español, espero no te moleste la edicion, o si no tengas una sugerencia. Asi ya hayan pasado las elecciones, puede servirnos en un futuro.

Comment: @IvanBotero muchas gracias por tu aportación. Completé la publicación indicando de dónde sale la puntuación de candidato, pues me di cuenta de que no estaba indicado.