# ¿Qué significa la "puntuación del candidato" vista en la elección de moderador?

Tags: soporte, elecciones, página-de-elecciones

En la [Elección de moderador 2017](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/) veo que cada candidato tiene una "puntuación", pero no comprendo su significado y, *en época de elecciones*, no puedo evitar relacionarlo a "cantidad de votos" que ha recibido.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Qué significa la "puntuación del candidato" vista en la elección de moderador?

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta fue contestada previamente aquí: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2487/

Comment: @toledano gracias, creo que ahora sería marcar esta pregunta como duplicada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entiendo que `1` punto por medalla requerida *(moderación,edición, participación)* además 1 punto por cada  `1k` de reputación.

El máximo serían 40 *( 20 de reputación , 8 por medallas de moderación , 6 por medallas de edición, 6 por medallas de participación)*

Answer (score -2):

Mecánicamente significa lo que [ha explicado Dev. Joel.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2580/301)
Realmente no significa casi nada.
Una persona no puede ser evaluada con un número.
Además, ciertos comportamientos recomendables te llevan a tener valores bajos, como [Pulsar Omitir](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1259/301).